# class PasswordEncoderSubsciber implements EventSubscriberInterface

Tags: symfony

When I create a user via a Post request thanks to Api platflorm, I want the transmitted password to be hashed before being inserted into a database ...

For the moment, the user is well created in bdd but password is always in clear. My subscriber therefore seems to be zapped ... but I don't understand why or how to debug ...

If someone has a lead I'm interested

my code

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\EventPriorities;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ViewEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class PasswordEncoderSubsciber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface
     */
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => ['encodePassword', EventPriorities::PRE_WRITE],
        ];
    }

    public function encodePassword(ViewEvent $event): void
    {
        $user = $event->getControllerResult();
        dd($user);
        $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();
        if ($user instanceof User && 'POST' === $method) {
            $hash = $this->encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());
            $user->setPassword($hash);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions in here should be written in English, not in French, sorry

Comment: I changed the language

Comment: The view event is sent when a controller action does not return a response.  Why would you think it is an appropriate place for hashing a password?  Typically you would encode the password in the same code the user is created.

Comment: Can you show us the User Entity and the url you use to create the user?

Comment: I have the hash here because I need to add it with pre_writh before adding it to the database

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be good, so verify that you you have setted the encoder in security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        # use your user class name here
        App\Entity\User:
            # bcrypt or argon2i are recommended
            # argon2i is more secure, but requires PHP 7.2 or the Sodium extension
            algorithm: argon2i
```

and try this code , it's more cleaner:

```
public function encodePassword(ViewEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getControllerResult();
    $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

    if (!$user instanceof User || Request::METHOD_POST !== $method) {
        return;
    }

    // encode password

    $user->setPassword(
        $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
            $user,
            $user->getPassword()
        )
    );

}
```